# how to cut string in pieces and send each of them via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth

There is a problem in the `for()` part of code, when i pass the value, it brings me the error:

> Array type expected; found:'java.lang.String

I don't know what to change, here is a piece of code, any piece of advice would be helpful.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String abc ="123!558#";
            for(int i=0; i<=abc.length();i++)
            {
                send(abc[i]); //here i get an error

private void send(String Value) {
    try {
        outputStream.write(Value.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: `charAt(i)`  // if you want to a char at a time, or `split`

Comment: change `i<=abc.length()` to `i<abc.length()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `CharAt(i)` in `for loop` it will help

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String abc ="123!558#";
            for(int i=0; i<abc.length();i++)
            {
                send(abc.charAt(i));

private void send(String Value) {
    try {
        outputStream.write(Value.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```